# Modal scrolls page down on opening

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm using Magnific Popup modal but this problem happened on CSS Modal as well so it appears to be related to my page layout. Whenever I open a modal, the page in the background will first scroll down by itself.
You can check it out here:
https://3rd-rock-2.myshopify.com/collections/all

Click on any product image

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The page is password protected.

Comment: Sorry, have removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem resides in the shopify **scripts.js** file. In the jquery ready function this is used (starting on row 79):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });
```

The code binds to every link (`<a />`) that has the `href` attribute starting with a `#`. In other words, binds to every anchor link. Shopify seems to want smooth scrolling from the anchor link to the anchor target.

So, you can try to prevent this. Maybe have a look in the Shopify documentations to see if there's a way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, you were right on. I thought that some script was bound to that event because some other weird stuff was happening due to preventDefault(); I wish I could upvote, thanks anyway!